# Do partition tables use logical block size or 512 bytes as the unit?

Tags: partition

When I read the partition table (MBR or GPT) from a device, are the numbers in units of logical block size, or nominal 512-byte sectors? Surprisingly, I couldn't find the canonical answer through googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Conclusion has been reversed based on further investigation**

Although almost all drives use 512-byte logical sectors, modern partition tables use LBA addresses, and LBA unit size is the logical sector size of the device, which today may be as great as 4096 bytes.

In the end I posted the question about unit size to the main GNU parted (partition editor) mailing list and have received [this response](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-parted/2016-09/msg00002.html).  Specifically:

"LBA always  refers to the drive's block size. So it may be 512 or 4096
or some other value, depending on what the drive reports."

Incorrect previous answer version: [[Partition tables (in the MBR and otherwise) refer to 512 byte blocks / logical sectors. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#PTE.]]

**Background information**

Reporting of disk physical disk sector sizes seems to be fundamentally done through commands in the ATA-8 specification, specifically the "IDENTIFY DEVICE" command. Compatibility issues (most often discussed) are alignment of I/O operations.  Apparently most drives handle 512 byte alignment, but with performance penalties, though there are some drives advertised as "4k native" or "4kn" that do not support 512 byte aligned I/O at all. In general, drives with physical 4k sectors use what is called "Advanced Format", which may help you search if you want more info.

This article https://linuxconfig.org/linux-wd-ears-advanced-format has some relatively clear discussion, especially if you are a Linux user. For what it's worth, on Linux the "parted -l" command reports physical and logical sector size, and parted also knows how to align partitions appropriately for Advanced Format devices.

Also, you might find this article http://www.seagate.com/tech-insights/advanced-format-4k-sector-hard-drives-master-ti/ informative and reassuring on the issue.

Comment: The Wikipedia article you linked seems to conflict with your answer: "address are **sector values** …. The sector size **used to be** considered fixed at 512" [emphasis mine]. And "For disks that present a sector size other than 512 bytes, such as USB external drives, … A sector size of 4,096 results in an eight-fold increase in the size of a partition that can be defined using MBR,"

Comment: Yeah, most of the documentation I've found talks about how partition tables should be written with consideration of the physical block size in mind, but never says anything about what to do with drives that have a logical block size other than 512. Now admittedly, I've never encountered such a beast in the field, and I suspect that storage devices will be presenting 512-byte logical block sizes for a long time to come, but I would like to future-proof my code by resolving this sooner rather than later.

Comment: True, this is all pretty confusing, and your points make sense. It still does appear to me that partition tables use 512 bytes as the units, based on use of LBA addressing.  The article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing states that "The current 48-bit LBA scheme, introduced in 2003 with the ATA-6 standard, allows addressing up to 128 PiB." The standards document at http://t13.org/Documents/UploadedDocuments/project/d1410r3b-ATA-ATAPI-6.pdf comments that 48 bit addressing allows for "approximately 144 peta bytes". So I am back again to believing that 512 bytes is the unit .

Comment: I suspect that the real take-away, for now at least, is expect a lot of software to break when used with new drives. (For the record, some years ago, I wrote a partition table editor that did some tricks to accommodate special partition alignment requirements in emmc memory for cell phones. I was updating it when I ran into this question — I don't want *my* tool to be one of the ones that break.)